# Nesting of xsl:when conditions

Tags: xslt

I have a query related to xsl choose , inside xsl choose is being used
Now i have two xsl:when condition is there like as hsown below

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test=$labcVar=$cde>
    <xsl:when test="$erf=$der">
      <xsl:value-of select="'edr'" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="'fre'" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
```

please advise is it the correct approach since insise xsl:when ..I have to begain only when first when condition becomes true the only I should go for second xsl:when condition, please advsie it is aloowed or not

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't nest a `when` directly inside a `when`, but you can use another `choose`:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test=$labcVar=$cde>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$erf=$der">
        <xsl:value-of select="'edr'" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="'fre'" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using `and`

```
<xsl:when test="$labcVar=$cde and $erf=$der">
    <xsl:value-of select="'edr'" />
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="'fre'" />
</xsl:otherwise>
```

Comment: That's different logic from the original question, where the `otherwise` applies when `$labcVar=$cde and not($erf=$der)`.

Comment: @IanRoberts: Aha, you're probably right. At that time, the question was a bit ill-formatted. I didn't attribute any semantics to these details.